# Conditional Formatting based on number in a cell that contains both text and numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

If cell A1 has the value "600 T" is there a way to apply the number less than/between/greater than conditonal formatting based on the number, essentially ignoring any text that may be in the cell?

Comment: If you conditionally format using a formula then you could conceivably parse the string to get just the numerical digits and then use the VALUE() function to check it's numerical value against your condition. It does require that you can find the numbers in the text so depends on the format of the string. If they all take the form 'nnn text' that is easy enough. Let me know if you need guidance on this.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? The cell will always start with a 3 or 4 digit number then a space and text.

Comment: Heya. I'm able to do less/greater than but having trouble with inbetween X and Y checks?

Comment: Sounds like you've got it all sorted? Sorry for not getting back to you, was at a social event. Guess you didn't need me in the end though, eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean operators such as `AND` already return TRUE or FALSE.

So this:

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))>=X,VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))<=Y),TRUE,FALSE)
```

… is equivalent to:

```
=AND(VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))>=X,VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))<=Y)
```

---

You can cast strings to numbers by multiplying by 1.

So this:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))
```

… is equivalent to:

```
=LEFT(A1,3)*1
```

---

Using these techniques reduces your formula:

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))>=X,VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))<=Y),TRUE,FALSE)
```

… to this:

```
=AND(LEFT(A1,3)*1>=X,LEFT(A1,3)*1<=Y)
```

---

Since your numbers may also have 4 digits, you can return the numeric portion like this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))
```

This *does* returns the space:  "600 "  … but that's not a problem since you're casting it to a number.

So your final formula would look like this:

```
=AND(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))*1>=X,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))*1<=Y)
```

**Update**

If your numbers *don't* include text, the above formula will fail with #VALUE!, because `FIND` is looking for a space that doesn't exist.

You can fix this by appending a space to `FIND`'s second argument.  So your true final formula will look like this:

```
=AND(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1&" "))*1>=X,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1&" "))*1<=Y)
```

Comment: Hello.
This doesn't seem to work. I think the problem may be that not every cell has numbers + text, some will just have a number and this formula searches for a space which doesnt exist in number only cells.

Comment: My answer was based on your comment that the data would always contain a space and text.  I'll update it when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))<=X
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))>=X
```

Checks if first 3 characters (if a number) of A1 is less or greater than X.

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))>=X,VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))<=Y),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Checks if first 3 characters (if a number) of A1 is between X and Y.

MID or RIGHT can be used instead to check digits in the middle or end of a string.

Comment: You can also use known separators such as space char in the sample data you gave and the use string length, find, and mid left right functions to identify numbers that are different lengths.